# What does 'Mapping windows' mean, in Cinnamon Settings, Appearance, Effects, Customize settings?

Tags: cinnamon, desktop-effects

Closing, minimizing, etc. make sense.  But what is 'Mapping windows':

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Oh, sorry, I think I see.  It means **opening** windows, or probably more accurately putting windows on your screen (opening and restoring).  (To figure it out, I turned off all effects but this one, and then starting banging windows around and it quickly then showed itself.)